# Skip first list item while iterating over the unordered list. JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, function, html-lists

I have an unordered list where the list items contain links to images. My code currently iterates over the list items, gets the `href`, creates a new image container within the div `banner-holder` and adds the `src` property.

What I want to do is skip the first list item as I already have that image within the `banner-holder` and I do not want to add it twice.

Thank you.

```
$('li').each(function ()
    {
        var bigImage = $(this).find('a.main-img').attr('href');

        $('<img/>').attr('src', bigImage).appendTo('#banner-holder');

    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('ul li').not(':first-child').each(function ()
    {
        var bigImage = $(this).find('a.main-img').attr('href');

        $('<img/>').attr('src', bigImage).appendTo('#banner-holder');

    });
```

Comment: jeez, didnt even think about :first-child. Kinda funny, been using that css3 selector for a while now with selectivizr and have been battling with IE issues with it! Thanks a lot, really helped me out!

Comment: yes, :first-child is covered by jquery to work in older versions of IE. To get round it if you are just using css, you would have to incorporate a selectivizr.js file, which makes older versions of IE behave like IE9 by allowing the user to use css3 selectors. Heres where to find the selectivizr file http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: That's what I though. It sounded like you were having problems with it in jq, not css, which is why I asked. I think modernizr does this for us.

Comment: I was using modernizr for a while but relized all it really did was list the html5 classes that the current browser supported in the header. Really didnt help me with past IE's. The problem is when JavaScript is disabled, that's when displaying a site in past versions of IE start to look very bad as 6-8 do not render css3 and html5 without help from JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery [`each` method](http://api.jquery.com/each) passes the index of the current item, so you could use that:

```
$('li').each(function (index)
{
    if (index > 0) { 
        var bigImage = $(this).find('a.main-img').attr('href');

        $('<img/>').attr('src', bigImage).appendTo('#banner-holder');
    }
});
```

Or, you could do it with the [`gt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
$('li:gt(0)').each(function() {
    ...
});
```

The current [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) has this note about the `gt` selector:

> Because :gt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :gt() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(index) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('li:not(:first-child)').each(function ()
    {
     var bigImage = $(this).find('a.main-img').attr('href');

      $('<img/>').attr('src', bigImage).appendTo('#banner-holder');

  });
```

i didnt test this but i think it will work.